# How are teachers culpable for scandal?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism, education

The Catechism of the Catholic Church refers to these people who are guilty of scandal

> Teachers who provoke their children to anger
>
> [CCC - 2286](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_P80.HTM#$2CO)

Is that teachers who are just being mean to their children (I would think that would be malice or some other sin, not scandal) or teachers who are provoking their children into becoming angry activists?

Answer (score 1):

Reminiscent of

> [Ephesians 6:4](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=56&ch=6&l=4-#x)
> And you, fathers, **provoke not your children to anger**: but bring them up in the discipline and correction of the Lord.

> [St. Thomas's commentary](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Eph6.htm)
> When he says **And you, fathers, provoke not your children to anger**, it is not that the fathers must give in to their will in all matters. Here it must be noted that the authority of a father with respect to his child is different from that of a master with respect to his servant. For the master employs his servant to his own advantage, but the father manages his child for the child’s advantage. It is necessary that fathers educate their children for the children’s own good; not, however, by excessively restricting or subjecting them.

and

> [Colossians 3:21](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=58&ch=3&l=21-#x)
> Fathers, **provoke not your children to indignation**, lest they be discouraged.

[St. Thomas's commentary on Colossians](https://isidore.co/aquinas/SSColossians.htm#34) for this verse is similar to his Ephesians one above.

Comment: I find it odd though, that the Catechism uses "teachers" and not "parents" in this paragraph.

Comment: @PeterTurner Parents are their children's primary teachers (though often they delegate their authority to others more competent in certain areas). The primary end of marriage is the procreation and education of children.

Answer (score 1):

CCC 2286-7 is referring to unintuitive extensions of scandal.  A teacher who prevents her students from learning would be causing scandal by indirectly leading them to do future evil through ignorance.  A teacher who angers her students is both preventing them from learning, and is undermining their trust in legitimate authorities (i.e. teachers).  I think this is the sort of thing the Catechism has in mind.  The simpler interpretation that provoking someone to sinful anger is a form of scandal makes sense but has nothing specifically to do with teachers, and so I think it is more than this.